# Adding thickness to image

Tags: image

I need help on adding thickness to the below PNG. Image I am trying to follow tutorials online but somehow they are not working for me . Would appreciate your help on this.

Eventually, we will use the boolean function to engrave this logo on another (shell) object that we need to 3D print.

Thank you in Advance
Mansi

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you are able to achieve, where your problem lies, what you want to achieve. If things "don't work for you", chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If instead of using a PNG, you make an svg out the PNG, could import that to Blender and use it  in 3D space

Comment: There's also an auto-trace route within Blender, but easier to do outside..

Answer (score 3):

You can import an svg and convert to mesh, if you do so ignore the first steps.

If you don't have any svg you can save your image as jpg or png with a white background and import it as *Image > Reference*, then *Object > Convert > Trace Image to Grease Pencil*:

[image]

Then <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Convert to > Bezier Curve*:

[image]

The bezier object will overlap so move the original:

[image]

Select the bezier object and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Convert to > Mesh*:

[image]

Switch to *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* in order to simplify:

[image]

Also press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* to merge all the overlapping vertices:

[image]

Fill the faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Then again do a *Limited Dissolve* in order to simplify the topology, now you can extrude:

[image]

If you plan to round the edges with bevels you'll need to work the topology of the faces a bit...