How to extrude images as plains to give it depth
is it possible to extrude an image in Blender? I have tried to solidify it with the Modifiers, and also convert to mesh. It does extrude the image, but it creates a blank gap in between the image.



No, the image border (since it is not actually the border, just the boundary between opaque and transparent) cannot be extruded. You have to shape the plane to fit the coin's outline. For example by using the Knife tool to cut along the boundary and delete the outer faces afterwards.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314023/adding-thickness-to-image https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture
